MYSQL Workbench Datetime Search Date
I have in my database a column that stores datetime values as shown in the image below. I want to search between two dates in the VATtransactn_date column

I have the below sql syntax
  SELECT * FROM mydb_stock.sql_vat WHERE VATtransactn_date >= '2024-06-16' AND VATtransactn_date <     DATE_ADD('2024-06-17', interval -1 second);

The results for the above syntax only produces date for '2024-06-16'. '2024-06-17' dates do not show up. Can anyone help me with this cos i have tried all i could. Thanks

Isn't it DATE_ADD('2024-06-17', interval -1 second) equal to 2024-06-16 23:59:59? Of course the data from 2024-06-17 does not show up.

The 2024-06-17 date value corresponds to midnight of that date, i.e. 2024-06-17 00:00:00. Subtracting one second puts you back in the previous day.
In query terms, executing:
SELECT DATE_ADD('2024-06-17', interval -1 second);

Will return:
DATE_ADD('2024-06-17', interval -1 second)
2024-06-16 23:59:59

Changing your query as follows should solve your issue:
SELECT * FROM mydb_stock.sql_vat
WHERE VATtransactn_date >= '2024-06-16' AND VATtransactn_date < '2024-06-18';


Ok. I tried using 'DATE_ADD('2024-06-17', interval 1 second)' but i still did not get the appropriate result.

why should i change it to  'SELECT * FROM mydb_stock.sql_vat
WHERE VATtransactn_date >= '2024-06-16' AND VATtransactn_date < '2024-06-18';'? My search range is '2024-06-17' and not '2024-06-18'

@KobbyAdom VATtransactn_date < '2024-06-18' excludes  '2024-06-18', but includes '2024-06-17 ' and also '2024-06-17 23:59:59'.

"Ok. I tried using 'DATE_ADD('2024-06-17', interval 1 second)'" Where did I suggest that? That will only include everything up to '2024-06-17 00:00:01'.

@prasad thanks. i do understand your explanation because i have implemented it and its working. Thanks

@Robby Cornelissen my bad. Sorry for the misunderstanding
